# Is there political pressure coming from developed countries against developing countries that don't have a relaxed software patent law system?

Tags: law, international-law

In China it used to be difficult to patent software without a hardware element, but recently they relaxed their laws to allow for a lot of patent software being claimed by private companies. Now, I am wondering if there's any kind of pressure applied by developed countries like the U.S. against developing countries that won't relax their software patent laws, and in what form these pressures might be applied.

Comment: "Relaxed" meaning "easier to obtain a patent"?

Comment: I don't think there is any consensus among developed countries on how to handle software patents. For example, in Europe software cannot be patented *in general*: [The European Patent Convention, Article 52](https://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/epc/2016/e/ar52.html): "The following in particular shall not be regarded as inventions within the meaning of paragraph 1: [....] (c)
schemes, rules and methods for performing mental acts, playing games or doing business, and programs for computers; " however, there are software patents granted for *inventions implemented via computors*.

Comment: @Hulk The same applies in the US. The US went on a software patent bonanza about 25 years ago. Neither the Patent Office nor the courts were happy with the way things were going, so the rules were tightened significantly. It is still possible to get a software patent in the US, but it is not easy.

Comment: Developed countries put lots of pressure to enforce iP laws on developing countries, e.g., in connection with free trade treaty negotiation. Software patents, however, are rarely a focus of those discussions which focus more on blatant commercial pirating.